# Is it possible to reload a Ruby script without restarting it?

Tags: ruby

I am writing an IRC service in Ruby.

Here is some code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

require "socket"

$SAFE=1

class IRC
    def initialize(server, port)
        @server = server
        @port = port
    end
end
```

At the moment when I change the code I kill the PID and restart it but I was wondering how to implement a sort-of 'rehash' to reload the code without restarting the process (causing a disconnect/connect).